# I don't know how to configure my rails app on Heroku to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

`ruby 3.1.1, rails 6.1.4`

I have a small Rails app on Heroku. I have a need to send emails from the app. There won't be a lot of emails, so I'd rather not add an app I have to pay for. I've set up emails in rails apps before (not on Heroku) and I've never had to get into the Heroku mail configuration/setup for smtp settings, password, user, port, etc., like in `config/production.rb`

Would someone be able to point me to any resources that explain this with examples?  And where I might find the proper settings for Heroku that I need for my app?

Thank you for any advice.

-jc

Comment: are you asking how to set the ENV variables in Heroku?   I have something like `<%= ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'] %>` or whatever you are using and all need, in the config file `production.rb` and then just set those variables in the Heroku dashboard for the app. Have you done any of that yet?

Comment: Rockwell Rice  Thanks, but I don't know what variables need to be set or what to set them too.  This part of send mail is new to me.  Never done this on Heroku before.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the service, you want to use for sending emails. Sendgrid would be a good option, it provides 300 emails/day for more information please [visit](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/). If you want to add an addon you can follow this [article](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid#details). [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on) you can find the details of the ENVs you need to set.

Also, make sure your ENVs in the mailer configurations should be the same with Heroku ENVs.
Sample Mailer configuration in

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 user_name: 'apikey', # This is the string literal 'apikey', NOT the ID of your API key
  password: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'], # This is the secret sendgrid API key which was issued during API key creation
  domain: 'yourdomain.com',
  address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port: 587,
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

You can find other mailing addons [here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/email-sms).